# does NEG instruction in assembly language sets the Overflow flag

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, eflags, signed-overflow

I want to know if the NEG instruction affects the overflow flag too. I know that it negates the value of a variable, but couldn't find out whether it affects the Overflow flag or not.

Comment: Why don't you check in the instruction set reference instead of asking here and waiting for an answer?

Comment: i viewed there but its really hard to got from there...need just a one to 2 line answer, i'm just new to this ..

Comment: [How does the NEG instruction set the adjust flag (AF) on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44837231) also explains that `neg x` sets flags according to `0 - x`, just like a `sub`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know what instructions do, consult the reference manuals.

The [essential reference, namely the Intel instruction set manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) says this about the NEG instruction:

```
Flags Affected
The CF flag set to 0 if the source operand is 0; otherwise it is set to 1.
The OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags are set according to the result.
```

So it is clear that the NEG instruction *sets* the O flag; therefore it *affects* the O flag, which is the OP's original question.  And it does so every time it is executed. (People should not confuse "didn't change" from "not set").

That particular reference manual doesn't provide a specific algorithm to indicate when O is set to zero or one.  However, Intel CPUs are 2's complement machines.  The Subtract instruction has the exact same verbiage.  NEG X is equivalent to  (0 SUBTRACT X).  So NEG should set the O bit according to "overflow" for (0 SUBTRACT X); this will set O when X is 0x8000000.

Inspecting the [Intel Basic Archiecture Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf), we find this description of the OF bit:

```
OF (bit 11) Overflow flag
— Set if the integer result is too large a positive number or too small a
  negative number (excluding the sign-bit) to fit in the destination operand;
  cleared otherwise. This flag indicates an overflow condition for signed-integer
 (two’s complement) arithmetic
```

confirming our understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you `neg`the value `80h`, the operand does not change, but the overflow flag is indeed set to `1`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28233977)

Comment: @DaemonPainter It does provide an Answer to the Question. It was just not nicely formatted.

Comment: @Scratte: It only barely provide a *new* answer; Ira's answer already gave the example of neg overflowing (and setting OF) on `0x8000000` (with 32-bit operand-size).  This answer just adds the resulting overflow value (unchanged) and reduces the operand-size to 8-bit operand-size (without mentioning the size; `neg eax` with eax=80h will produce `0xffffff80` without overflowing.)  On the whole, I don't think this answer needs deletion, but I didn't upvote because its example is too minimal: you already need to understand it to know which operand-size it's talking about, for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is all very reasonable. Deleting this as a subject matter expert is always an option. Deleting it via the Low Quality Post queue, that only serves to validate a "Not an Answer" flag, is an entirely different matter. That queue is not meant to be an early access to 20K privileges.

Comment: @Scratte: right, agreed, it does answer the question.  It's arguably "low quality", but not "very low quality", so neither flag delete reason is justified.  And it's not just a copy/paste of part of Ira's answer (which would justify deletion), it's just a paraphrase or independent statement of the only special case.

Comment: I apologize for being wrong in my evaluation of the post. Please don't take this personally, but the barely provide a new answer could have been added as a comment under the already available answer. The amount of added information is so low that could have been a very low quality. This is why we have multiple reviewers :)